# How can I find the maximum value

Tags: php

```
<?php
$all = array();
enter code here
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 100 ; $i++){
$ric=sqrt($i);
if(is_int($ric) == true){
    $all[] = $i;
    
}
}
$max = max($all);
$min = min($all);
echo "MIN=".$min."<br>";
echo "MAX=".$max;
```

Hello I changed my codes and instead of `if((int)$ric - $ric == 0)` I write this `if(is_int($ric) == true)` but it gets me wrong.What is the problem? please help me out.

Comment: assuming `max()` is the PHP inbuilt `max()` it is used to find the largest value in an array. You dont have and have not created an array

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put all the `$i` that satisfy the condition into an array. You can then use the `min()` and `max()` functions to get the minimum and maximum values.

```
<?php
$all_i = [];
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 100 ; $i++){
    $ric=sqrt($i);
    if((int)$ric - $ric == 0){
        $all_i[] = $i;
    }
}
$max_i = max($all_i);
$min_i = min($all_i);
echo "Min = $min_i<br>Max = $max_i<br>";
echo "All = " . implode(", ", $all_i) . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man your answer was very useful for me but could you please help me out to find the minimum of $i and please tell me that can we create an array with $i?

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Quote mismatch `echo 'Min ` ... `<br>";`.

Comment: Barmar could you please help me?

Comment: Everything you wanted is in the answer. What don't you understand?